# When will the population of the town be aprox $175000$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

By analyzing the impact of growing economic conditions, a demographer establishes that the predicted population, $P$, of a town $t$ years from now can be modeled by the following function:
$$
P(t) = 6t^4 - 5t^3 + 200t + 12000.
$$
I'm stumped, I tried setting the two sides equal to each other and factoring but I'm probably doing something wrong. Any help?

Comment: approx. 13 years: [wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=6t^4+-+5t^3+%2B+200t+%2B+12000-175000)

Answer (score 1):

By substituting various positive integers into the equation $P(t)$, we see that $t = 13$, because $P(13) = 174981 \approx 175000$.
It is not a trivial problem if the question requires to solve for the exact value of $t$, but here we only require that the population be close to $175000$, so it is simply a matter of plugging in a few values into the equation and seeing which one is the best fit.

Comment: Thanks a ton, I was trying to work around subbing integers, I thought there was another way